Resolving a guard that depends on a service that uses afterRender to initialize its value
I have a service that depends on localStorage to initialize its state Observable, so it has to be initialized using afterRender - call it MyService. I then have a guard function, myGuard, that depends on MyService, and pipes MyService.state$ to return an Observable<boolean>.
The problem (I think) is that the guard prevents the page from rendering, and therefore prevents the service from initializing its value, resulting in an incomplete Observable in the guard. I know that this can be solved by injecting the service into a component, but I was hoping to find a way using guards, especially that I'm using the guard on quite a few routes.
The error I'm getting is Internal Server Error: Page /abc did not render in 30 seconds
MyService
export class MyService {
  private _state$ = new BehaviorSubject<MyState>('loading');

  public get state$() {
    return this._state$.asObservable();
  }

  constructor() {
    this._init();
  }

  private _init() {
    afterRender(() => {
      this._updateState();
    });
  }

  private _updateState() {
    const val = localStorage.getItem(_myKey) || 'unavailable'
    this._state$.next(val);
  }
}

MyGuard
export const myGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state): Observable<boolean> => {
  const service = inject(MyService);
  const router = inject(Router);
  const isValid$ = service.state$.pipe(
    filter((value) => value !== 'loading'),
    take(1),
    map((val, _) => {
      const isValid = val === 'valid';
      if (!isValid) {
         router.navigate(['codeValidation']);
      }
      return isValid;
    })
  );

  return isValid$;
};



If you on the server, directly return true, instead of running the observable sequence.
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

export const myGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state): Observable<boolean> => {
  const service = inject(MyService);
  const router = inject(Router);
  const platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  const isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  const isValid$ = isBrowser ? service.state$.pipe(
    filter((value) => value !== 'loading'),
    take(1),
    map((val, _) => {
      const isValid = val === 'valid';
      if (!isValid) {
         router.navigate(['codeValidation']);
      }
      return isValid;
    })
  ) : true;

  return isValid$;
};


unfortunately, that is not it. I need to take the first value that is not 'loading'. Having take(1) also passes 'loading', which will be filtered out by filter. Your code produces an error: no elements in sequence. I think the problem is that the component needs to be rendered before the service could emit values, but rendering is supressed by the guard. I.e: afterRender is not running.

@hman_codes updated my answer!
